# Openlayers 3 : popup by geojson file

Tags: javascript, geojson, openlayers-3

How do you put GeoJSON attribute information in a popup with OpenLayers 3

I need to display the informations included in my geojson file into the popup. Here is my method but it gives me undefined.

My GeoJson file:

```
{ "type": "FeatureCollection", "features": [{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "name": "Caen - Campus 3 "}, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [-0.353538,49.148791] } }, { "type": "Feature", "properties": { "name": "Caen "}, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [-0.369770,49.184403] } }
```

Here is my method

```
var element = document.getElementById('popup');

var popup = new ol.Overlay({

  element: element

});

map.addOverlay(popup)


map.on('click', function(evt){

  var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
  function(feature, layer) {

return feature;


});

  if ( feature ) {
var geometry = feature.getGeometry();
var coord = geometry.getCoordinates();

var nom = feature.getProperties();
//var nam = nom.type;
popup.setPosition(coord);
$(element).popover({
  'placement': 'top',
  'html': true,
  'content': '<p>'+feature.get('name')+'</p>'
});
$(element).popover('show');

  } else {
$(element).popover('destroy');


}

});
```

I create the popup when I click on it displays me 'undefined'. I think that don't use the good method to put the 'name' object included on the GeoJson file: `feature.get('name')`

I think that I don't uses the best method. Thank for your help.

Comment: Your code does not look wrong. Maybe you can provide a JSFiddle to test? Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/zt2tyzqo/2/